# How to find the traffic sources for a YouTube video?

Tags: analytics, video, youtube, viral-marketing

My web site is mentioned very favorably in a third party video that was posted to YouTube.  We have the video embedded on the website as "social proof" that you should use our site.

In the last week that video started getting thousands of views on YouTube (not through our site).   We noticed this because there was an increase in direct traffic and brand searches.  The view count of the video on the YouTube site is rising rapidly.

Is there any way for us to figure out why this video is getting so much traffic?  We'd like to know where it was shared and by whom.

The video was paid for and produced by a third party.   As such, we don't have any access to the YouTube channel to which it was posted.

Comment: Yo Stephen whats the URL of the video in question out of interest? I have various methods but may not work if the video is really really new.

Comment: Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ksEycoNy0E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any tools for this (seeing as you don't have access to the stats). Your best bet is to Google the following, using double quotes for an exact match:

1. The URL of the video.
2. The short URL of the video.
3. The exact title of the video.
4. The name of the channel that uploaded the video.

Also, check to see if it has been added to a popular playlist, or if another video of theirs has gone viral, resulting in a knock-on effect (I've witnessed this a number of times).

Comment: How do I find the short URL of the video?   Can you add more information about checking popular playlists? I'm not sure where to start looking for that.

Comment: Click on the share option on a Youtube video and you will be given a short URL. It'll look something like http://youtu.be/ID_GOES_HERE Does the channel have any playlists? Have any of their videos gone viral in the last while?